# How do I remove HTML encoded characters from a string?

Tags: ruby, string, html-parsing

I have a string which contains some HTML encoded characters and I want to remove them:

```
"&lt;div&gt;Hi All,&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"paragraph_break\"&gt;&lt; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;Starting today we are initiating PoLS.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"paragraph_break\"&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;Please use the following communication protocols:&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;1. Task Breakup and allocation - Gravity&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;2. All mail communications - BC messages&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;3. Reports on PoC / Spikes: Writeboard&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;4. Non story related tasks: BC To-Do&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;5. All UI and HTML will communicated to you through BC.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;6. For File sharing, we'll be using Dropbox.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;7. Use Skype for lighter and generic desicussions. However, in case you need any approvals, data for later reference, etc, then please use BC. PoLS conversation has been created on skype.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"paragraph_break\"&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;You'll have been given necessary accesses to all these portals. Please start using them judiciously.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"paragraph_break\"&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;All the best!&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"paragraph_break\"&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;Thanks,&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;Saurav&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
```

Comment: What did you try? And what happened when you tried?

Comment: Can you please add the expected result? Is kind of hard to understand what you really need . Not sure if you want to remove them or just decode them. May be you need to remove some and decode others?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you want to do is doable many ways. Perhaps looking at why you might want to do that will help. Usually when I want to remove encoded HTML, I want to recover the contents of the HTML. Ruby has some modules that make it easy.

```
require 'cgi'
require 'nokogiri'

html = "&lt;div&gt;Hi All,&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"paragraph_break\"&gt;&lt; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;Starting today we are initiating PoLS.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"paragraph_break\"&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;Please use the following communication protocols:&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;1. Task Breakup and allocation - Gravity&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;2. All mail communications - BC messages&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;3. Reports on PoC / Spikes: Writeboard&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;4. Non story related tasks: BC To-Do&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;5. All UI and HTML will communicated to you through BC.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;6. For File sharing, we'll be using Dropbox.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;7. Use Skype for lighter and generic desicussions. However, in case you need any approvals, data for later reference, etc, then please use BC. PoLS conversation has been created on skype.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"paragraph_break\"&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;You'll have been given necessary accesses to all these portals. Please start using them judiciously.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"paragraph_break\"&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;All the best!&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"paragraph_break\"&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;Thanks,&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;Saurav&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"

puts CGI.unescapeHTML(html)
```

which outputs:

```
<div>Hi All,</div><div class="paragraph_break">< /></div><div>Starting today we are initiating PoLS.</div><div class="paragraph_break"><br /></div><div>Please use the following communication protocols:<br /></div><div>1. Task Breakup and allocation - Gravity<br /></div><div>2. All mail communications - BC messages<br /></div><div>3. Reports on PoC / Spikes: Writeboard<br /></div><div>4. Non story related tasks: BC To-Do<br /></div><div>5. All UI and HTML will communicated to you through BC.<br /></div><div>6. For File sharing, we'll be using Dropbox.<br /></div><div>7. Use Skype for lighter and generic desicussions. However, in case you need any approvals, data for later reference, etc, then please use BC. PoLS conversation has been created on skype.</div><div class="paragraph_break"><br /></div><div>You'll have been given necessary accesses to all these portals. Please start using them judiciously.</div><div class="paragraph_break"><br /></div><div>All the best!</div><div class="paragraph_break"><br /></div><div>Thanks,<br /></div><div>Saurav<br /></div>
```

If I want to take it a step farther and remove the tags, retrieving all the text:

```
puts Nokogiri::HTML(CGI.unescapeHTML(html)).content
```

Will output:

```
Hi All,Starting today we are initiating PoLS.Please use the following communication protocols:1. Task Breakup and allocation - Gravity2. All mail communications - BC messages3. Reports on PoC / Spikes: Writeboard4. Non story related tasks: BC To-Do5. All UI and HTML will communicated to you through BC.6. For File sharing, we'll be using Dropbox.7. Use Skype for lighter and generic desicussions. However, in case you need any approvals, data for later reference, etc, then please use BC. PoLS conversation has been created on skype.You'll have been given necessary accesses to all these portals. Please start using them judiciously.All the best!Thanks,Saurav
```

Which is where I usually want to get when I see that sort of string.

Ruby's [CGI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescape) makes encoding and decoding HTML easy. The [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) gem makes it easy to remove the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think the **easiest** way to do this is, Assuming you want to use the html in the string.

```
raw CGI.unescapeHTML('The string you want to manipulate')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have assigned that string to a variable `s`, is this the result you want?

```
puts s.gsub(/&lt;[^&]*&gt;/, '')
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest:

```
clean = str.gsub /&lt;.+?&gt;/, ''
```

Comment: -1 for suggesting a regex without mentioning their limitations for HTML.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm It isn't HTML at this point. It's a string with the potential to be HTML.

Comment: Still, @theTinMan your answer is way better.