# Use map to build a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Active Record result and looking to return a simple data set for a HIghCharts chart like this demo:

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic

The data is a simple hash:

```
[{
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 61.41,
         }, {
            name: 'Internet Explorer',
            y: 11.84
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.85
        }, {
            name: 'Edge',
            y: 4.67
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.18
        }, {
            name: 'Sogou Explorer',
            y: 1.64
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 1.6
        }, {
            name: 'QQ',
            y: 1.2
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            y: 2.61
        }]
```

How do I use .map (i.e. Record.all.map { |r| etc... } to output this?

I have tried a few times myself and the structure is all mangled and the output includes html encodes characters for the quotes etc.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@vendors.map { |v|  { name: v.name, y: v.expenditures.invoices.sum(&:amount).to_f } }
```

This spits out:

```
    [
{:name=&gt;&quot;ABC Ltd.&quot;, :y=&gt;13382.0},
{:name=&gt;&quot;EFG Inc&quot;, :y=&gt;0.0},
{:name=&gt;&quot;ZWY Ltd.&quot;, :y=&gt;0.0},
{:name=&gt;&quot;Apple&quot;, :y=&gt;21539.4},
{:name=&gt;&quot;Microsoft&quot;, :y=&gt;0.0},
{:name=&gt;&quot;Amazon&quot;, :y=&gt;12345.0}
]
```

The hashes have the :key=>'data' format but with everything html escaped.

Comment: You want an array of hashes right?

Comment: Yes - cleaned up my question with better example of what I have tried.

Comment: Add the current data you have you're trying to map.

Comment: "The data is a simple hash" no, the data is a json object in the browser, not a ruby hash on the server; your issue appears to be (since you have code that properly maps and creates the hashes) the ruby hash is being html-escaped and you want json to be put into the high charts script. For that, I feel perhaps a rewording of the question to high light this as well as including the html where you are rendering this hash (which is supposed to be json)

Comment: Ok.. I think the solution will be to add escape_javascript for the HTML escaping in the view.  There is no end user data being fed into this so it’s safe.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `records` table includes these attributes `name`, `x`, `y`, `sliced`, `selected`.

If this is the case, you can generate the describing dataset by doing following code snippet:

```
Record.all.map do |record|
  record.attributes.symbolize_keys.slice(:name, :x, :y, :sliced, :selected).compact
end
```

Here is the explanation for the code:

- `attributes` returns a list of attributes from the schema in a hash, each key is a string
- `symbolize_keys` converts each key from string to symbol
- `slice` to select only necessary keys
- `compact` to remove keys with `nil` value.

Comment: I like this answer. Personally, I'm a stickler about trying to make the active record call as efficient as possible. In that spirit I would run something like:

`Record.select(:name, :x, :y, :sliced, :selected).order(:name).map { |record| record.attributes } `

calling 'select' on active record will ensure you're only pulling the values you want from the database. I think it'll ignore associations as well if any exists for those values. 

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.8/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes

Comment: Hmm... I never considered that one of my data points is through an association i.e. record.associated_model.sum(:amount) etc.  Not as easy as you answered.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your values are appearing with html escaping. This answer worked for me with your code example:
[How do I remove HTML encoded characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929006/how-do-i-remove-html-encoded-characters-from-a-string)

From there you could wrap your values around

```
require 'cgi'
require 'nokogiri'
@vendors.map { |v|  { name: CGI.unescapeHTML(v.name), y: CGI.unescapeHTML(v.expenditures.invoices.sum(&:amount)).to_f } }
```

and get an answer close to what you want. That looks pretty gross to me... I might try to clean up the data before saving to your DB so you don't have to fight this every time you query.

Then you can try and get fancy with something like:

```
sums_by_id = Vendor.joins(expenditures: :invoices).group('vendors.id').sum(:amount)
Vendor.select(:id, :name).order(:name).map { |v|  { name: v.name, y: sums_by_id[v.id].to_f } }
```

This might look a little pokey, but if you've got LOTS of records to iterate through via your @vendors object you probably don't want to have to contact the database for each record to run that sum association.

Comment: I agree on the refactoring. Mine is not very efficient - wanted to get the data output first. I am outputting this into the Highchart JavaScript in my view. This may be escaping issue.